# Error when trying to instantiate new object

Tags: c++, class, struct, instantiation

I have a class AdventureGame which has a constructor.  When I try to make a new AdventureGame object, I receive the error "no matching function for call to 'AdventureGame::AdventureGame()'

Here is some of my class, the constructor, and main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class AdventureGame 
{
private:
public:
    int playerPos;
    int ogrePos;
    int treasurePos;
    string location;

    AdventureGame(int ogre, int treasure) 
    {
        playerPos = -1;
        ogrePos = ogre;
        treasurePos = treasure;
        location = "";
    }; 

.
.
.  // other functions that I'm sure are irrelevant
.
.

    int main() 
    {
        AdventureGame game;
        int numMoves = 0;
        std::string move;

        while (!game.isGameOver(game.playerPos)) 
        {
            game.printDescription(game.playerPos);
            cout << "Which direction would you like to move? (forward, left, or right)" << endl;
            cin >> move;
            game.move(move);
            numMoves++;
        }
    }
```

How do I create a new game?

Comment: Read the error again. You have an explicit constructor in the class with the signature `AdventureGame(int ogre, int treasure)`. This removes the default constructor automatically generated by the compiler otherwise. So either you have to remove the explicit constructor or call the explicit constructor in your code instead of the default. Look : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor expects two parameter you need to pass them.

Like this for instance:

AdventureGame game(3,5);

Answer (score 0):

You should either create an empty constructor:

```
AdventureGame() 
{
    playerPos = -1;
    ogrePos = 0;
    treasurePos = 0;
    location = "";
};
```

or always create your class passing ogrePos and treasurePos values to it:

```
    AdventureGame game(0,0);
```

Probably it makes sense to create both empty and parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a default constructor without defining it. Just calling `AdventureGame game;` calls a constructor function `AdventureGame() {};` which is not defined. In order to call AdventureGame(int ogre, int treasure) write `AdventureGame game (arg1, arg2)` in the main function.

If you are using C++11 I would suggest the best practice will be always create new object with this format `AdventureGame game {}`. Using this format, `AdventureGame game {}` calls Default Constructor and `AdventureGame game {arg1, arg2 ...}` calls some other corresponding constructor.

Note that `AdventureGame game ();` DOES NOT call default constructor!!

Enjoy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Defualt Constructor is missing

```
AdventureGame() 
{
    playerPos = -1;
    ogrePos = 0;
    treasurePos = 0;
    location = "";
}
```